# header: when ohead is multiline, ihead moves up. How to align both at same bottom level

Tags: pdftex, header-footer

I am adding ohead and ihead in my page as follows. `ohead` is multiline. because of that i head move up above the headsepline. How to bring it back to the headsepline

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=true,footsepline=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\color[RGB]{84,84,84}
\ohead{\onehalfspacing \upshape PUR\hspace*{3mm}\linebreak 5x[16/16][1/1]\hspace*{3mm}}
\ihead{\upshape \hspace{3mm}[17-20/44][1/6][1-2/2][23-26/50][4-7/12]}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\footnotesize}
\begin{document}
\KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:328.70039pt,paper=landscape}
\recalctypearea
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using two `tabular`s you can adjust the `\ihead` to have a blank top line, making it bottom aligned.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=true,footsepline=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\color[RGB]{84,84,84}
\ohead{\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}PUR\\5x[16/16][1/1]\end{tabular}\hspace{3mm}}
\ihead{\hspace{3mm}\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}\\\relax[17-20/44][1/6][1-2/2][23-26/50][4-7/12]\end{tabular}}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\footnotesize\onehalfspacing}
\begin{document}
\KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:328.70039pt,paper=landscape}
\recalctypearea
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]